# JetBrains IDEs live templates - place multiple carets

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider, live-templates

In IntelliJ live templates one can use `$END$` to specify where the cursor should be placed once the template is expanded.

Is there a way to place multiple carets? Specifying multiple `$END$` locations doesn't work. I sometimes need to type the same text into several places for what can be an auto-generated piece and that would be a nice expansion of functionality.

Currently as a solution I use "surround templates" where I can first type some text and then use `$SELECTION` variable.

Comment: *"In IntelliJ live templates one can use `$END$` to specify where the cursor should be placed once the template is expanded."* Yes, it will be, but in the simplest case. `$END$` specifies where the caret will be placed when all placeholders/variables will be resolved. And if you have no variables .. then yes, it will work that way.

Comment: Please provide a code sample/your template where it can be clearly seen where you want your inputs to be made (i.e. "this is what I have and this is what I want to make in the end/final result"). Based on your description so far, just having a variable (the same one) in those places should do the job for you.